# UICollectionView cell drawing issues swift

Tags: ios, swift2

In my porject I  have `uicolelctionview` and custom cell. In `collectionView:CellForItemAtIndexPath` I get the custom cell

```
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCollectionCell
```

and add this code

```
cell.personImage.layer.cornerRadius=(cell.bounds.size.height-10)/2
cell.personImage.layer.borderWidth=3
cell.personImage.layer.masksToBounds=true
```

I was hopping to get this type of view:

[image]

but some of cells appears like this:

[image]

and I have to reloatData to get current cell view.
Still cant understand why I get this bug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to set dynamic corner radius with the following code:

```
cell.personImage.layer.cornerRadius = cell.personImage.frame.width / 2.0
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Yep, that should work. I was oblivious to that before 2 seconds ago when I was using my playground.

Comment: I believe, this solution should bring ideal circles. Narek can also play with cell.frame but as it goes from his explanation one should use some pre-calculated multiplier to achieve the same result.

Comment: Yes its exactly what i want,but i noticed one strange thing,when i scrolling colelctionview some of cells redrawing like ideal circles,but some of them becomes rounded but not ideal circles.I dont get why collectionview updated while scrolling.Can i turn off this?

Comment: Check out your ImageView settings and constraints in Storyboard. Check out if in the Attributes in inspector "Mode" is set either to "Scale to Fill" or "Aspect Fill". If "Aspect Fit" is chosen make sure that "Clip Subviews" is checked.

Comment: Reformatting my previous comment: check out your ImageView settings  in Storyboard in the Attributes inspector: "Mode" should be set either to "Scale to Fill" or "Aspect Fill". If "Aspect Fit" is chosen make sure that "Clip Subviews" is checked.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you see the images shaped "diamond like" is because `cornerRadius` is set to a dynamic int at the moment, and it's set to something more then half of itself. The cornerRadius you should be using needs to be a lot less then `(cell.bounds.size.height-10)/2`.

as Michael said, try using something like:

```
cell.personImage.layer.cornerRadius = testView.frame.width / 2
```

and see what your outcome is.

Comment: I set 3 and 10 and more.Unfortunately its doesnt work,if you want i can add images to my post

Comment: See if using 0.3 or smaller works. Do you know the size of `cell.personIMage`?

Comment: No i dont know the size of the cell.PersonImage.0.3 also doesnt works,beacuse its too small.I have to connect cornerRadius to cell.bounds because of different size of devices.If I set static number in one size of device it will work correctly and in other size of device not.And look at images i have posted,some cells draw correctly and after reloadingData evrything looks perfect

Comment: So, when you use 0.3, there is a square? What does that look like?

Comment: Yes.`(cell.bounds.size.height-10)/2` equals 40.7 and if i set this to `cornerRadius` and after reloading its drawing correctly.BTW thanks for answers